# Install Phonegap for Windows Phone 7

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, cordova, sdk

Good morning,
I'm new in phonegap and I installed it on a Windows 7 machine. I installed the correct sdk for Android as explained here (http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0//guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide) and all works correctly. Now I want to develop an app for windows phone 7. I tried to follow the instruction but it don't work. I downloaded the sdk for windows phone 7.1, I installed it and now I have the visual studio express for windows phone. For android I write on the command prompt phonegap run android, and automatically the adv generate a device and run the app. How can I do this for wp7?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to install the last version of phonegap for windows phone 7 you need to do the following steps:

- Download and install the Windows Phone SDK
- Download and extract the latest copy of PhoneGap
- Go to lib\windows-phone and run createTemplates.bat . It will generate 2 zip files: one for WP7 and one for WP8
- Copy the CordovaWP7_x_x_x.zip file to the \My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ProjectTemplates\ directory.
- Open Visual Studio
- Create a new Project and select Cordova project
- Run it